# Windows terminal ubuntu how to change starting directory

Tags: windows-terminal

I am wondering how to change the starting directory of my windows terminal from `/home/user/` to `C:/Users/user`. I tried a few things I found, but nothings works. This is my current profile specified in the settings.json file:

```
{
  "acrylicOpacity" : 1,
  "closeOnExit" : true,
  "colorScheme" : "One Half Dark",
  "commandline" : "ubuntu",
  "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF",
  "cursorShape" : "bar",
  "fontFace" : "Consolas",
  "fontSize" : 10,
  "guid" : "{ba50f801-2d96-4517-a737-575f32f0fb61}",
  "historySize" : 9001,
  "icon" : "C:/Users/user/Pictures/ubuntu.png",
  "name" : "Ubuntu",
  "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
  "snapOnInput" : true,
  "startingDirectory" : "C:\\Users\\user",
  "useAcrylic" : true
}
```

but when I open the terminal the prompt is `user@laptop:~$` and `pwd` gives `/home/user/`

Comment: add `"source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you mean `wsl`, you can set `startingDirectory` just like this:

```
"startingDirectory": "//wsl$/Ubuntu/home/user"
```

You can explore the path `\\wsl$` in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Works for most cases, but not for `//wsl$/Ubuntu/mnt/c` - it seems that `mnt/c` is only resolved after the `startingDirectory` is set. Oscar's answer below provided the fix in this case.

Comment: This `//wsl$/Ubuntu/home/username` is the only one that works for me in WT Preview 1.8, simply input the text in the _Settings > Profiles > Ubuntu > Starting directory_ and click the _Save_ button.

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to change my Command line in the settings from `ubuntu.exe` to `wsl.exe -d Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me (on Windows Terminal 1.0.1401.0, WSL2 and Ubuntu 20.04):

```
"startingDirectory": "C:/Users/user"
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions here didn't work for me in Nov 2023, but adding the line below to the bottom of the  ~/.bashrc file does the trick:

`cd /mnt/d/dev`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there was an auto-generated ubuntu profile in addition to the one I created. I started using the auto-generated one and removed the `"commandline" : "ubuntu"` option and it now listens to the `startingDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked when i added the version number: `//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/username`

Answer (score 0):

To change the starting directory of windows terminal:

- **Open windows terminal settings**

[image]

- **Go to Ubuntu profile page and change "Starting Directory" to `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\<user>`**

[image]

Note: I posted another answer cause it did not work for me using forward slashes